# Options passed to Soundmanager (via Soundcloud JS SDK) not being used

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I've got a little codepen set up [here](http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/FgDIh) to demonstrate my issue.

Created an object to hold a few options, which is passed as an argument to the stream method.

```
var custom_options = {
  multiShot: false
  , onplay: function() {
    SC_STATE.playing();
    SC.playing = true;
  }
  , whileplaying: function() {
    SC_STATE.updating(SC.current_track.position, SC.current_track.durationEstimate);
  }

},
SC_STATE = {
  playing : function(id) {
        this.el.unbind('click').click( function() {
            SC.current_track.pause();
    });     
  }
  , updating : function(position, estimate) {
    var percentage = (position / estimate) * 100;
        this.played.css('width', this.round(percentage) + "%");
  }
}
```

The `#sc-played` element ought to expand in width as the sound plays, but it doesn't! This function,

```
options = { url: "http://soundcloud.com/tokyospeirs/flightless-bird" };
SC.get('/resolve', options, function(track) {
    SC.stream('/tracks/' + track.id, custom_options, function(track) {
        track.play() 
    });
});
```

Is being told to use the `custom_options` above, and that includes the `whileplaying` method. This was working a little while ago. Something new in the sc sdk that I'm missing? Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Yes, i'm experiencing the same issue too! Apparently, event handlers are supposed to be provided in soundManager.setup(), according to SoundManager2's documentation (see http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/, "Bonus: Extended soundManager.setup() Parameters"). The problem is that SoundCloud's SDK does not allow to pass parameters to this function...

Comment: ... or it could also be caused by this commit: "Removed SoundManager2
and replaced it with a minified version of AudioManager.", https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/3ee64f9a9864078348a445a51a3b133933ac74b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soundcloud commited breaking changes to their SDK recently, according to [their git history](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commits/master).

Tracks are now played using [AudioManager](https://connect.soundcloud.com/audiomanager/audiomanager.js) instead of SoundManager2, so the API has changed.

If you want to be notified when your track starts playing, use the following code:

```
SC.stream('/tracks/' + track.id, custom_options, function(track){
  track.on("stateChange", function(evt){
    if (evt=="playing") // do your business here
  });
});
```

If you want to be notified regularly about the progress of a playing track, use this:

```
  track.on("positionChange", function(pos, len){
    // do your thing here
  });
```

Comment: Apparently, Soundcloud reverted to the original version of their SDK... So you won't need to implement my code for now.

Comment: Looks like they're still deciding what route they ought to go. Getting 404s on http://connect.soundcloud.com/audiomanager/audiomanager.js at current. Will mark your answer as correct when they sort themselves out. ;)

Comment: ...aaaaaand the rollback's complete: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/64dbb7000106a3e887abe3d6c8b6166e8fc98ad4#diff-da29df6756ac058798137fc7f3265a64

Comment: Thanks so much for the reassurance that I hadn't gone crazy, though. That was very much appreciated.